Is Surya and Surya Narayana Upanishad the same or are they different
I was looking at Openn and found Sūryātharvaśirasupaniṣad and Sūryanārāyaṇopaniṣad. So are these two scriptures the same and if they're different how so? Also is the first Upanishad the Surya Upanishad commonly known?
